# What is the max number of "dropped" items in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I've stumbled upon an [old forum thread](http://www.xboxachievements.com/forum/showthread.php?t=379189) saying the limit for ["dropped" (floating) items](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_(entity)) is 200. Obviously items de-spawn after certain conditions are met (5 minutes in survival on PC), but the threads I found were concerning extremely large automated wheat farms whereas manually farming would gain a higher harvest than the automatic farm (because of the 200 items limit).

Can I get an answer that specifies the exact maximum number of dropped items for the latest version of Minecraft for each platform? The Gamepedia article I linked to above specifies that:

> On the console edition the item entity limit is 200 in loaded chunks.

I've yet to confirm whether this is outdated information or not and my searching hasn't landed me with a specific number for the PC version, either. I'd also like to know the limit for pocket and pi editions.

Comment: Since those three games are entirely separate, questions should not be asked about all of those (unless it's specifically about comparisons between them, which are usually pointless as well, because they are three different games). Since this question is pretty old, I assume that you mean the "legacy console edition". If it's the new one, please change the tag to [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition].

Answer (score -2):

In Bukkit/Spigot this is configurable, in Vanilla I would say that there is no limit.

Comment: Having a source for this info would be helpful in improving this answer.

Comment: In vanilla there is no built-in limit; the practical limit is the server's performance, leading to growing lag and eventually a crash in case of an excess. There's enough questions how to fix the server crashing upon player entering the End after leaving a gravity block duper running too long here.

Comment: I can confirm @SF. One day I wanted to convert a mountain to gold with the wand mod. Screwed up the item ID. Got signs that can't stack. All of those not on the first level popped. Game went to 1 FPS until I killed it. If there was a limit of items on the ground it would have stopped putting them on the ground before my game became a slideshow.

Comment: This answer addresses entirely the wrong game.